# Declaring arraylist object (java)

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Basically I'm making a blackjack game so first thing I did was make the object "card".

```
public class Card {

  int number;
  int suit;

  public static final String[] NUMBERS = {null, null, "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
  public static final String[] SUITS = {"Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts"};

  public Card(int number, int suit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.suit = suit;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return NUMBERS[number] + " of " + SUITS[suit];
  }
}
```

Next thing I did was make an array list of cards called cardlist and then something called deck which is a cardlist with the standard cards:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CardList {

  public String name;
  public ArrayList<Card> cards;

  public CardList(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public Card getCard(int i) {
    return cards.get(i);
  }

  public int howManyCards() {
    return cards.size();
  }

  public void addCard(Card card) {
    cards.add(card);
  }
}
```

and then the deck:

```
public class Deck extends CardList {

  public Deck(String name) {
    super(name);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (int j = 2; j < 15; j++) {
        addCard(new Card(j,i));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anyways after that I began making the game like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlackJack {

  public static String[] getNames(int players) {

    System.out.println("What are the names of the players?");
    String[] playerNames = new String[players];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < players; i++) {
      playerNames[i] = input.next();
    }
    return playerNames;
  }

  public static int peoplePlaying() {

    System.out.println("How many people are playing?");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int players = input.nextInt();

    return players;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int players = peoplePlaying();

    String[] playerNames = getNames(players);

    Deck deck = new Deck;

    System.out.println(deck);

  }
}
```

The second to last line is my failed attempt to declare a deck to then use with the rest of the program. As deck is an array list I don't know to correctly declare it. When I created the object Deck I made it so it just needed a String as its name and would already have made the 52 cards but I'm not sure exactly how that works as you can tell.

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: As a style point, consider using an enum for the card suit and the card value as opposed to String arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deck extends CardList and CardList requires "String name" parameter in constructor. This structure obviously made for, Players can have cardList, deck is a cardList and so on... so if you want to get rid of to pass that argument, your code should be like this,

```
public Deck() {
   this("default_deck_name");
   //this will call the current Class' constructor which has a String Parameter, --> Deck(String name) 
}

public Deck(String name) 
{
   super(name);
   //this will call the Parent Class(CardList)'s constructor which has a String parameter

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     for (int j = 2; j < 15; j++) {
       addCard(new Card(j,i));
     }
   }
}
```

with this way you dont need to pass the name argument when creating Deck

```
Deck defaultDeck = new Deck(); // this will create Deck instance with name default_deck_name
```

if you want to create Deck with specific name you can use the code below

```
Deck defaultDeck = new Deck("specific_name");
```

this is called **constructor overloading**.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a constructor

```
public Deck(String name)
```

so to create a Deck you need to give it a name like

```
Deck deck = new Deck(PlayerName[0]);
```

This is where using the auto-complete in your IDE will step you through writing this.